Android studio - saving audio files to media store - doesn´t display album name, artist name etc
When I try to save my audio files to media store, it saves the file with the appropriate name, but the album name and artist name that I specify is not saved. With this code, it worked on my older andorid 10 device, but now as I test on android 14 I cannot see it.
Is there mabye a new way to do it on newer versions? I haven´t been able to find a solution.
fun saveToExternalStorage(mp3Path: String, title: String, 
 artist:String, album: String, context: Context): Boolean {
 val contentResolver = context.contentResolver
 val audioCollection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)

val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
    put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, title)
    put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, artist)
    put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM, album)
    put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, "Music")
    //put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, mp3Path)
    put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3")

}
return try {
    contentResolver.insert(audioCollection, contentValues)?.also { uri ->
        contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri)?.use { outputStream ->
            FileInputStream(File(mp3Path)).use { inputStream ->
                inputStream.copyTo(outputStream)
            }
        }
    }
    true
} catch (e: IOException) {
    e.printStackTrace()
    false
}

}

